# Does gzip work on the development server?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Does gzip work on the python development server for appengine?  How can I test this in the future?

Note: I've used Firebug to look at my HTTP requests from the browser, and I see that Accept-Encoding is set to "gzip,deflate".

Comment: update: I looked at the response headers for deployments to a devserver, and to google.  The Content-Encoding header is set to gzip for the google deployment, but not for the devserver.  It appears that the devserver may not gzip responses consistently with the production servers.

Answer (score 0):

to see if the server responds with gzip encoded headers look for

> Content-Encoding:gzip

in the response headers

€: found this in their [faq](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/kb/general.html)

> Google App Engine does its best to serve gzipped content to browsers that support it. Taking advantage of this scheme is automatic and requires no modifications to applications.
>
> We use a combination of request
>   headers (Accept-Encoding, User-Agent)
>   and response headers (Content-Type) to
>   determine whether or not the end-user
>   can take advantage of gzipped content.
>   This approach avoids some well-known
>   bugs with gzipped content in popular
>   browsers. To force gzipped content to
>   be served, clients may supply 'gzip'
>   as the value of both the
>   Accept-Encoding and User-Agent request
>   headers. Content will never be gzipped
>   if no Accept-Encoding header is
>   present.

Comment: if this was the answer you were looking for i would kindly ask that you accept it